# Items not correctly spread across GridLayout

Tags: qt, qml, grid-layout, qtquick2

I have the following custom QML `Item`, which will represent a pin code entry GUI element:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3

import "../items"

Item
{
    id: ueKeypad

    width: 512
    height: 512

    Rectangle
    {
        id: ueKeypadWrapper
        antialiasing: true

        anchors.fill: parent

        ColumnLayout
        {
            id: ueKeypadLayoutMain
            antialiasing: true

            layoutDirection: Qt.LeftToRight
            spacing: 8

            anchors.fill: parent

            ColumnLayout
            {
                id: ueKeypadTitleLayout

                layoutDirection: Qt.LeftToRight

                Layout.fillWidth: true

                Layout.minimumHeight: 24
                Layout.preferredHeight: 24
                Layout.maximumHeight: 24

                Text
                {
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.fillHeight: true

                    text: qsTr("PIN ENTRY")
                    clip: true
                    font.bold: true
                    font.pointSize: 24
                    textFormat: Text.RichText
                    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                }   // Text
            }   // ColumnLayout

            GridLayout
            {
                id: ueKeypadNumbersLayout

                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true

                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignVCenter

                layoutDirection: Qt.LeftToRight

                columnSpacing: 8
                rowSpacing: 8

                flow: GridLayout.LeftToRight

                columns: 3

                UeButton
                {
                    id: ueKeypadButton1

                    Layout.minimumHeight: 32
                    Layout.preferredHeight: 32
                    Layout.maximumHeight: 32

                    ueText: qsTr("1")
                }

                UeButton
                {
                    id: ueKeypadButton2

                    Layout.minimumHeight: 32
                    Layout.preferredHeight: 32
                    Layout.maximumHeight: 32

                    ueText: qsTr("2")
                }

                UeButton
                {
                    id: ueKeypadButton3

                    Layout.minimumHeight: 32
                    Layout.preferredHeight: 32
                    Layout.maximumHeight: 32

                    ueText: qsTr("3")
                }

                UeButton
                {
                    id: ueKeypadButton4

                    Layout.minimumHeight: 32
                    Layout.preferredHeight: 32
                    Layout.maximumHeight: 32

                    ueText: qsTr("4")
                }

                UeButton
                {
                    id: ueKeypadButton5

                    Layout.minimumHeight: 32
                    Layout.preferredHeight: 32
                    Layout.maximumHeight: 32

                    ueText: qsTr("5")
                }

                UeButton
                {
                    id: ueKeypadButton6

                    Layout.minimumHeight: 32
                    Layout.preferredHeight: 32
                    Layout.maximumHeight: 32

                    ueText: qsTr("6")
                }

                UeButton
                {
                    id: ueKeypadButton7

                    Layout.minimumHeight: 32
                    Layout.preferredHeight: 32
                    Layout.maximumHeight: 32

                    ueText: qsTr("7")
                }

                UeButton
                {
                    id: ueKeypadButton8

                    Layout.minimumHeight: 32
                    Layout.preferredHeight: 32
                    Layout.maximumHeight: 32

                    ueText: qsTr("8")
                }

                UeButton
                {
                    id: ueKeypadButton9

                    Layout.minimumHeight: 32
                    Layout.preferredHeight: 32
                    Layout.maximumHeight: 32

                    ueText: qsTr("9")
                }
            }   // GridLayout

            RowLayout
            {
                id: ueKeypadActionLayout

                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true

                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignVCenter

                layoutDirection: Qt.LeftToRight

                spacing: 8

                UeButton
                {
                    id: ueKeypadButtonOk

                    ueText: qsTr("Ok")
                }   // UeButton

                UeButton
                {
                    id: ueKeypadButton0

                    ueText: qsTr("0")

                    Layout.minimumHeight: 32
                    Layout.preferredHeight: 32
                    Layout.maximumHeight: 32
                }   // UeButton

                UeButton
                {
                    id: ueKeypadButtonCancel

                    ueText: qsTr("Cancel")
                }   // UeButton
            }   // RowLayout
        }   // ColumnLayout
    }   // Rectangle
}   // Item
```

It uses custom QML `Button`, named `UeButton`:

```
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick 2.5

Button
{
    property string ueText

    id: ueButton

    text: ueText

    style: ButtonStyle
    {
        background: Rectangle
        {
            antialiasing: true
            smooth: true
            gradient: Gradient
            {
                GradientStop
                {
                    position: 0
                    color: "#ffffff"
                }   // GradientStop

                GradientStop
                {
                    position: 0.418
                    color: "#000000"
                }   // GradientStop
            }   // Gradient

            border.color: "steelblue"
            border.width: control.activeFocus?2:1
            radius: 4
        }   // background

        label: Text
        {
            color: "#ffffff"
            font.bold: true
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            font.pointSize: 16

            text: control.text
        }   // label
    }   // ButtonStyle
}   // ueButton
```

If I view first code in QtCreator's Designer Tool, I get the following situation:

[image: Problem Screenshot]

Why are `Button`s not spread across `GridLayout`? Same goes to lower `RowLayout`, whose `Item`s (three `Item`s of type `UeButton`) are not centered and aligned across whole `RowLayout`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The attached properties of a `Layout` ensures that the `Item`s contained are correctly sized w.r.t. the given constraints.

`Item`s can be stretched to fill the available space (`fillWidth`/`fillHeight`), forced to not shrink under a certain value (`minimumWidth`/`minimumHeight`) or not enlarge over a certain other value (`maximumWidth`/`maximumHeight`). You can also force an `Item` to occupy more than one row/column (`rowSpan`/`columnSpan`) and to assume a specific size (`preferredWidth`/`preferredHeight` which implies `minimum` == `maximum`).

The precedence is:

`preferred` <`minimum`/`maximum` < `width`/`height`

Setting a property to the left automatically discard any to the right. You can easily understand the reasoning behind this. This scheme can be somewhat "broken" by `implicitWidth/implicitHeight` since the size of any `Item` cannot shrink under these values. `fill` properties ensure that the `Item` fills the available space, according to the constrains above: if `fill` is not defined an `Item` cannot grow or shrink according to its constrains.

Now, if you want the `Button`s to maintain they aspect and still stretch the grid, you can use an *intermediate* `Item`. While applying `Layout` attached properties to the external `Item`, the `Button`s can be `centerIn` it and be unaffected.

Sample code:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    width: 200; height: 200; minimumHeight: 100; visible: true

    GridLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        rows: 3
        columns: 3

        Repeater {
            model: 9

            Item {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true

                Button { anchors.centerIn: parent; width: 32; height: 32; text: index + 1 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Instead if you want the `Button`s to fill the available space, just specify `fillWidth`/`fillHeight`. Since no other layout constraints are set (e.g. `minimum*`, `maximum*`) the `Button`s correctly occupy all the available space. Here is the code above revisited. As expected, `width` and `height` are simply discarded:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    width: 200; height: 200; minimumHeight: 100; visible: true

    GridLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        rows: 3
        columns: 3

        Repeater {
            model: 9

            Button {width: 32; height: 32; text: index + 1;   // 32? NOPE!
                Layout.fillWidth: true; Layout.fillHeight: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```