# Set maximum width for RowLayout

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

I'm trying to build a custom control where I can place other controls (`Button`s, `Slider`s, edit fields, etc.) grouped together.

The control should appear on the right side of the window and should have a fixed `width` of `200`. This works fine:

```
RowLayout {
    Item {
        Layout.fillWidth: true
    }
    MyControl {
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.preferredWidth: 200
    }
}
```

Now the problem is with the layouts and controls I used inside `MyControl`.
I'm using a `Rectangle` with a `ColumnControl` in it and in the `ColumnControl` nested the GroupBoxes (see code below).

In one of the `GroupBox`es I want to place several `Button`s in a row so I am using a `RowLayout` (I tried `Row` also, same result). If I only put two or three `Button`s in a row the `Button`s get stretched to fill the entire width and everything is fine. But when I use more `Button`s, they are not shrinked below a certain size. Instead the `RowLayout` grows to the right and some of the `Button`s are not visible since they are positioned outside the window.

It seems that the `RowLayout` calculates the size of it's children first and then resizes itself. Now what I want is that the `RowLayout` is fixed to the parent `width` and the children are shrinked to fit into the parent.

I managed to do that with a workaround but I'm not happy with that. There must be a more elegant way. I also tried to set the `width` of the `RowLayout` to the `parent.width` but got binding loops. Everything looked fine but I don't want to write code which starts with a couple of warnings.

Here's the code of the control:

```
Rectangle {
    id: rootRect

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 4

        GroupBox {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            title: "GroupBox Title"

            RowLayout {
                id: buttonGroupWithWorkaround
                enabled: false
                anchors.fill: parent

                //the workaround:
                property int numberOfButtons: 6
                property int buttonWidth: (rootRect.width - 2 * buttonGroupWithWorkaround.spacing) / numberOfButtons - buttonGroupWithWorkaround.spacing

                Button {
                    Layout.preferredWidth: buttonGroupWithWorkaround.buttonWidth
                    text: "|<"
                }
                Button {
                    Layout.preferredWidth: buttonGroupWithWorkaround.buttonWidth
                    text: "<<"
                }
                Button {
                    Layout.preferredWidth: buttonGroupWithWorkaround.buttonWidth
                    text: "<"
                }
                Button {
                    Layout.preferredWidth: buttonGroupWithWorkaround.buttonWidth
                    text: ">"
                }
                Button {
                    Layout.preferredWidth: buttonGroupWithWorkaround.buttonWidth
                    text: ">>"
                }
                Button {
                    Layout.preferredWidth: buttonGroupWithWorkaround.buttonWidth
                    text: ">|"
                }
            }
        }

        GroupBox {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            title: "NextGroupBox Title"

            RowLayout {
                id: theButtonGroup
                enabled: false
                anchors.fill: parent

                Button {
                    //this doesn't work
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    text: "|<"
                }
                Button {
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    text: "<<"
                }
                Button {
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    text: "<"
                }
                Button {
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    text: ">"
                }
                Button {
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    text: ">>"
                }
                Button {
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    text: ">|"
                }
            }
        }

        GroupBox {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            title: "OtherGroupBox Title"
            //some other controls
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sizing can be sometimes a little bit tricky.

`fillWidth` ensures that the `Button`s *grow* or *shrink* to fill the available space. However, this behaviour is not arbitrary. It follows other constraints set on the `Item`. In particular the size is never shrunk under the [`implicitWidth`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#implicitWidth-prop) of the `Item`.

Hence, in this case you can solve the issue by setting a smaller `implicitWidth`, like this:

```
Button {
    Layout.fillWidth: true
    text: ">"
    implicitWidth: 20     // the minimum width will be 20!
}
```

Alternatively you can define a custom `ButtonStyle` which defines a well-sized [`label`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-styles-buttonstyle.html#label-prop) but it really sounds overkilling in this specific case.

Have also a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33003235/2538363)  (or other resources on SO) to have a better grasp about layouts/sizing.